# Out-File path format is not supported

Tags: powershell

I am grabbing the last line of a file and outputing it in another file with the same name with a "t" prefix but an errors comes up.

```
$path   = 'D:\files\'
$inc = @("*txt_*")
$exc = @("*csv_*")
$List = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse -include $inc -exclude $exc

foreach ($item in $List) {
    Get-Content $item.Fullname -Tail 1 | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $path"t-"$item
}
```

[image]

However, if I dont prepend the file name it works fine.

```
Get-Content $item.Fullname -Tail 1 | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $path"t-"
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Add this command inside our `foreach` loop: `Write-Host $path"t-"$item`. How do you think, is value being printed valid filename or not?

Comment: `"$($path)t-$($item.name)"`. $item is an object and not a string. Which part of that do you want there... just the name?

Comment: i want to output the same file name with a "T-" prefix in front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend the filename with `T-` and build the destination path from the folder name and the modified filename:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Include $inc -Exclude $exc | ForEach-Object {
  $dst = Join-Path $_.Directory.FullName ($_.Name -replace '^', 'T-')
  Get-Content $_.FullName -Tail 1 | Set-Content $dst -Encoding ascii
}
```

Comment: I am fetching the last line of each file to another file, i need both files to exists.